# Deploy and undeploy in Tomcat6 from Putty Command line

Tags: tomcat6, ubuntu-12.04

I have an Ubuntu Server (12.04) with Tomcat 6, I can go to the server and from the GUI deploy and undeploy... but of course I want to deploy and undeploy remotely from the putty command line.

I have found this command to undeploy, but it doesn't have any effect:

```
wget "http://admin:admin@localhost:8080/manager/undeploy?path=/BoCM_WebApp_Tomcat" -O - -q
```

Another solution I have found is to delete the files in  /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps  but that does not undeploy the service, and it is a dirty solution.

Any idea?

thanks in advance.

Comment: and if you simply replace the war in the webapps directory? Take a look at this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html specially to the `autoDeploy` parameter

Comment: Just replacing the .war file in the webapps folder, and resetting tomcat, the app will be redeployed?

Comment: From the doc: _It is possible to deploy web applications to a running Tomcat server. If the Host autoDeploy attribute is "true", the Host will attempt to deploy and update web applications dynamically, as needed, for example if a new .WAR is dropped into the appBase. For this to work, the Host needs to have background processing enabled which is the default configuration._

Comment: Ok, seems ok, just to replace the . War file.